# Dynamic thumbnail with correct aspect ratio

Tags: php, image, thumbnails

Im trying to create thumbnails for my image upload script, and i succeeded! But i got a minor problem. Im using [pixlie](https://github.com/SteffenHagdorn/Pixlie/) to create the thumbnails if you're familiar with it.
Im trying to get the same size and effect as if i used `style="width:200px; height:auto;"`
I want to keep the aspect ratio of my thumbnails and im not quite there yet.

My code so far is (im not sure about my "math") :

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($uploaddir);
$width = imagesx($img); //get width and height of original image
$height = imagesy($img);
$maxwidth = '200';

//scaling
if ($height < $width) {
  $ratio = $height / $width;   
  $newheight = $ratio * $height;   
  $newwidth = $maxwidth;  
}
elseif ($height > $width) {
  $ratio = $height / $width;
  $newheight = $ratio * $maxwidth;
  $newwidth = $maxwidth;
}

require_once('Pixlie.php');

$pixlie = new Pixlie();
$pixlie->setCache(new PixlieFileCache('thumbnail_img/'));
$thumbnail = new PixlieRenderOptions();
$thumbnail->setWidth($newwidth);
$thumbnail->setHeight($newheight);
$image = $pixlie->render("$uploaddir", $thumbnail);
```

And if you're not familiar with [pixlie](https://github.com/SteffenHagdorn/Pixlie/) it might be hard to help me. But maybe you can help me with the math or you might have something better than pixlie.. idk.
(Some thumbs are getting re-sized pretty well but others gets real.. oblong.. ?)

Thanks beforehand for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm...you're sure there is no maximum height? To have a correct aspect ratio this should be OK:

```
// Scaling
$newwidth = $maxwidth;
$ratio = $width / $height;
$newheight = $newwidth / ratio;
```

So the width would always be 200 and the height accordingly.